# PdfReader returning error reading pdf file

Tags: .net, itext, pdf-reader

I am using the latest version of the iTextSharp using iTextSharp.dll with .net service. When the service tries to read the pdf file using PdfReader(filename), it faces an exception with the exception message being: "Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection". Has anyone faced this and what could be causing this?
Thank you,
I do windows now.

Comment: iTextSharp.dll is "version 5.5.10".

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please review our [SO Question Checklist](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) to help you to ask a good question, and thus get a good answer.

Comment: Please share the pdf in question to allow analysis of the issue